# How do I resolve 'NativeAnimatedNodesManager.connectAnimatedNodes' crash on my React Native app?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

in our react native app we continuously getting a crash "NativeAnimatedNodesManager.connectAnimatedNodes"
Here is Screen shot of stack trace[Screen shot of stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YK5s.png)
and here is stack trace

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: connectAnimatedNodes: Animated node with tag (child) [279] does not exist
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.connectAnimatedNodes(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:367)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$16.execute(NativeAnimatedModule.java:778)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$ConcurrentOperationQueue.executeBatch(NativeAnimatedModule.java:173)
       at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule$3.execute(NativeAnimatedModule.java:359)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$UIBlockOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:579)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:915)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1026)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2600(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1086)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:175)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1035)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:775)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7952)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1022)

FrescoIoBoundExecutor-1:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.PriorityThreadFactory$1.run(PriorityThreadFactory.java:52)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

|Smartlook_ANR_WatchDog|:
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:451)
       at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:356)
       at com.smartlook.b.run(SourceFile:12)

Firebase-Messaging-Task:
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2067)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1092)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Please share you solutions
ThankYou